# Error reading lmdb file in caffe net

Tags: neural-network, protocol-buffers, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

I am trying to use the LMDB file that I created to define the data layer in caffe net and I get below error

> ```
> TypeError: 'LMDB' has type (type 'str'), but expected one of: (type 'int', type 'long')
> ```

I checked for labels in the text file that I passed to script that generates lmdb file (`caffe/build/tools/convert_imageset`).
Am I missing something here?

Edit -1:
Here is my data layer definition:

```
n.data,n.labels = L.Data(batch_size = batch_size, 
                         source=lmdb_src, 
                         backend = "LMDB", 
                         transform_param = dict(mean_file = mean_file),
                         ntop=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to set

```
backend: "LMDB"
```

in your net definition, instead of

```
backend: LMDB
```

Note that `LMDB` is *not* passed as string, but rather as an enumerated integer.

What you should do is set

```
backend = caffe.Data.LMDB
```

Use the enum value set by caffe protobuff definition.

Comment: @VenkataDikshitPappu 1. do not post code in comments it can't be read. 2. what is the value of LMDB? Please edit your question with sample code that reproduces the error

Comment: I have added the snippet to the question

Comment: got it I used the enum value and it worked!! thanks :)

Comment: When I try to do: `caffe.Data.LMDB` I receive: *AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DB'* @Shai